# Study path for learning 3D Rigidbody physics?

Tags: physics, self-learning, 3d

My goal is to understand how to describe the motion and rotation of 3D Rigidbody objects when you apply forces to them in various locations.  How do physicists describe rotation in 3D?  I think I already have a handle on linear motion in 3D(Velocity vectors), but I don't know what adding rotation into the mix does.  The fact that I don't even know *what* it is I need to know is really making it hard for me.

I know I only talked about motion and rotation as being the things I wanted to learn, but that was just the starting point, what about collisions?  How about multi bodys?  How about finite element stress?  Or soft bodies?

I would like to understand how all of this stuff is related.  I want to form a study plan that takes it one step at a time, and makes it possible to reach achievable goals.  The problem is knowing what order to study things in?  Should I learn about liked bodies while I'm still thinking of rigidbodies as points, or save that for after I am already comfortable with rotations?

What are harmonic oscillators? what are Quaternions?  What do I need in order to understand them?

I have searched around google, but I'm having trouble finding a concrete study plan.  I would like some kind of "roadmap" that would show me the right path to take, with all the prerequisites I need to know.

I also find it hard to find clear explanations of things on google, I'm sure there are many great resources out there, but I'm having trouble finding them.

There are so many disciplines out there that use physics, like the different types of engineering that all require vastly different kinds of problems, what I'm looking for is to reach a general knowledge of this stuff so I can chart a course in a more specific direction later.

My current mathematical skills are basic algebra(solving for unknowns and so on), and a basic understanding of geometry and trigonometry (the pythagorean theorem, sin cos tan, and so on.)

Thank you to anyone who took the time to read my question, and in advance to anyone who answers!

Comment: I'm not qualified to answer all the stuff about a learning track (I'm in high school) but a harmonic oscillator is simply a system that when displaced, falls in motion due to a restoring force, F = kx, proportional to distance (think a spring moving back and forth or a pendulum swinging at a small theta). All you need is algebra to have a basic understanding, but classical mechanics and simple differential equations would be necessary for a deeper level of understanding. However, the graphs of this motion are sinusoidal so trig functions are also required to understand oscillations.